# How to place linear layout and relative layout side by side

Tags: android, android-layout

Trying create a XML file for ListView item like this:

[image: Item]

Here I didn't how to create a XML file for this UI. I tried by taking two TextViews (Left blue box content) in one LinearLayout and remaining content(right blue box content) in one RelativeLayout. I didn't get how to place two layouts side by side. if my approach is wrong then please suggest suitable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach was good, the only thing is that you have to get the two separate layouts next to each other. You can simply put the layouts inside a LinearLayout and set the orientation to `horizontal`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!--Left box (Solved)-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">
        <!--Right box (Level with progressbar)-->
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the two layouts inside another LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.